# NPM - Node error when building Angular App ELIFECYCLE - errno 139 after installing angular cli

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Today i installed angular-cli, i had an issue where i couldn't install it at first because of missing permissions, later i installed it with sudo npm install, that caused me problems which i couldn't fix whole day today so im forced to ask this question here..

When i build frontend part of my application i get this error:

```
[INFO] > node ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
[INFO] 
[INFO] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[INFO] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[INFO] npm ERR! errno 139
[INFO] npm ERR! app-fe@1.2.0 mavenbuild: `node ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod`
[INFO] npm ERR! Exit status 139
[INFO] npm ERR! 
[INFO] npm ERR! Failed at the app-fe@1.2.0 mavenbuild script.
[INFO] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[INFO] 
[INFO] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[INFO] npm ERR!     /home/nikola/.npm/_logs/2020-07-10T16_08_21_554Z-debug.log
```

What's important to mention is that i could build my application successfully today before i installed angular-cli. No changes are made in the application, other people from my team can build it but i cant due to these issues.

This is the whole log: https://pastebin.com/srAAQXmn

I saw a post which said that i mada a mistake when i used SUDO to install anything with npm but i cannot find any solution...